# What exactly happens at the second-order phase transition of the 2D Toric code?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, topological-order

For a 2D Toric code specified by

$$H = -J_s\sum_{s} \prod_{j\in s} \sigma^x_j - J_p\sum_{p} \prod_{j\in p} \sigma^z_p - h_x\sum_{l} \sigma^x_l - h_z\sum_{l} \sigma^z_l$$
where $s$ denotes stars, $p$ denotes plackets, and $l$ denotes links, there are known to be critical values of $h_x$ and $h_z$ that mark second-order phase transitions. In particular, the regime with the weaker external field is characterized by "confined excitations" while the regime with the stronger external field is characterized by "condensation" of those excitations. What do the wave functions and energies of states in these phases look like mathematically, and what causes this phase transition to occur?

When $h_x=0$, and $h_z=\infty$, I can see that the ground state is given by the "all-up" state in the $\sigma^z$ basis which is an equal superposition of all states in the $\sigma^x$ basis:
$$|\uparrow_1\dots \uparrow_N\rangle = (|\leftarrow\rangle + |\rightarrow\rangle)^{\otimes N}$$
so this state looks like a condensate of $x$-type bosons (electric charges). However, I am not sure what happens in the other regimes of each phase when $h_z$ is finite.

Answer (score 6):

The ground state of the toric code can be understand as a superposition of all loop configurations in the $z$ basis. The fact that these loops fluctuate at all length scales (and thus around the torus) leads to the topological order in the system.

The $\sigma_z$ terms lead to a "tension" in the loops, penalizing long loops. Eventually, this tension will make very long loops impossible, giving rise to a "typical loop length" which is independent of the system size (similar to a correlation length) and lead to a phase transition to a trivial phase.

The $\sigma_x$ term does similar things in a dual basis.  (In some sense, it leads to a "breaking of loops", though one has to be careful with this picture.)

Note that this is only a qualitative, not an exact, picture of the ground state. In fact, already the Toric Code with only a $z$ field maps to the 3D classical Ising model for which no exact solution is known.

This phase transition has been studied by various means, see e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1740 and the references therein.

Comment: When you say, "eventually, this tension will make very long loops impossible", why does this happen? Why does a critical value of h_z exist? An explanation in the way of competing effects would suffice; an explanation incorporating symmetries of Toric code would also be great. An example of a classical competing effects-type argument is as follows:

In the 2D Ising ferromagnet in zero field, the phase transition between the ordered and disordered phases can be thought of in terms of the entropic term (TS) becoming dominant over U in the free energy at some critical temperature.

Comment: @pointofnoreturn If you consider loops in the $z$ basis, the competing effects are given by the $\sigma_x^{\otimes 4}$ term, which wants the loops to fluctuate independent of their size, and the $\sigma_z$ magnetic field terms, which wants the loops to be short.

Comment: Excellent. What about a symmetry-based perspective to this transition? It is not clear to me the connection between the symmetries and this critical tension picture.

Comment: A related paper that studied this topological phase transition in detail is http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.070602.

Comment: @pointofnoreturn In principle, there is no (local) symmetry involved, since there is no local order parameter for a topological phase transition.  You can, of course, use duality mapping such as the one to the 3D Ising model discussed in the paper linked by Meng Cheng, where it corresponds to a symmetry-breaking phase transition.